# Error bar not aligning after Dodge and Filling Color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a question on the following dataset that's graphing properly. Here is the data:

```
weight  group   max    mean    min
1         1     2.3      3       4
1         2     2.3      3       4
1         3     2.5      3       4
2         1     1.5      2       3
2         2     1.5      2       3
2         3     1.5      2       3
3         1     4.2      5     5.4
3         2      4       5     5.6
3         3     3        5     5.8
```

Here is my code:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplus)

sk4$mean <- as.numeric(as.character(sk4$mean))

sk4$min <- as.numeric(as.character(sk4$min))

sk4$max <- as.numeric(as.character(sk4$max))


sk4$group[sk4$group==1] <- "X"
sk4$group[sk4$group==2] <- "Y"
sk4$group[sk4$group==3] <- "Z"
# convert every column to numeric if character now
bold.text <- element_text(face = "bold")



# plot values seem a little wonky but the plot is coming together
ggplot(sk4, aes(x = as.factor(weight), y = mean, color = as.factor(group), width=.5)) +
  geom_bar( stat = "identity", size=0.5, position = "dodge", fill = "white") +

  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = max, ymin = min), width=.2, position = "dodge") +
  theme_bw(base_size=10) + 
  theme(axis.text = bold.text) + 
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10),
        axis.title=element_text(size=12,face="bold")) +
  theme(axis.title = bold.text) +
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.position = "bottom") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  ggtitle("T")+ 
  xlab("A") + 
  ylab("B") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1", "2", "3"),
                   labels=c("A", "B", "C"))+ 
  theme(legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=10, face="bold"))+
  scale_colour_manual(name="legend", values=c("black", "#808080", "#844082")) + 
  scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("X" = "black", "Y" = "orange", "Z" = "blue"))
```

[image]

I am unsure why the legend X, Y, Z is not filling as values "*values = c("X" = "black", "Y" = "orange", "Z" = "blue")*". Also, the alignments for the error bars are not aligning. I looked up for potential solutions but cannot find anything. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can set the amount of dodging manually by specifying `position = position_dodge(0.5)` instead of just `"dodge"`.

Comment: Thank worked perfectly - thank you for the suggestion. Any suggestions on the fill-in?

Comment: You need to specify a `fill` aesthetic as well as `color`, e.g. `aes(..., color = factor(group), fill = factor(group))`